# break cycle if tcorrect text introduced?

Tags: c#, text, cycle, break

I need to find a way for to stop a cycle/loop if correct text is introduced, as if multiple tasks were running.

Anybody who can help me?

Comment: By "cycle" do you mean "loop"?

Comment: Like bash.d said, it's difficult to understand what you're asking - loop, thread, etc.

Comment: if (state=="wrong") break;

Comment: be elaborate. So that people can understand you get correct answer.

Comment: yeah, by cycle I mean loop.

Comment: I need to create a code that prints up text randomly, this operation should be broken when a correct "password" is introduced.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a loop you can 'stop the cycle' with [`break;`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/adbctzc4.aspx).

```
for (int i = 0; i < someLength; i++) {
  if (someText == someotherText) {
    break;  
  }
}
```

This will only break out of the *current* loop - that is, it "terminates the closest enclosing loop" - mind you, so if you're in a nested loop it will 'fall' into the next and continue *that* cycle.